# jQuery loop overwriting HTML

Tags: jquery, html, text, each, overwrite

I have a site, with lots of paragraphs.

I want to highlight certain words, based on terms that are in a JSON file.

I manage to get it work, but it is only highlighting the last word of the dictionary, because the last each loop constantly overwrites the html.

I've tried several solutions, because the source of the problem is simple, but I constantly fail and none of them worked.

Do you have any idea, where can I start looking?

Here is the jQuery / JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var dictionary = <?php echo($dictionary)?>;
    dictionary = jQuery.parseJSON(dictionary);

    $('p').each(function() {
        var parse = $(this);

        $.each(dictionary, function( index, value ) {
                var str = parse.text();

                parse.html( str.replace(value,'<u>' + value + '</u>'));
        });
    });
});
```

The performance of the code is a thing that worries me too, but I will struggle with it once this is solved.

EDIT:

The JSON is very simple:

```
[
 {"term1":"value1"},
 {"term2":"value2"},
 ...
]
```

EDIT 2:

Paragraphs are generated in a php loop resulting in a structure like:

```
Container
  row
    p
    p
    p
    ...
```

EDIT 3:

Finally solved in the server, with a super easy php foreach loop.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `dictionary` and your `p`s?

Comment: That's how [`$.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) works... [Documentation exists for a reason](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Comment: where did the source variable come from?

Comment: `parse.html( str.replace(value,'<u>' + value + '</u>'));`  try this

Comment: Sorry, you are right, when copy and paste, I did a mistake. Not working although.

Comment: `var str = parse.text();` - this will get the text, and ignore any HTML tags. Try ` var str = parse.html();` instead to get all of it. Otherwise, when you write it back again, you will have effectively stripped out all of the HTML that was previously inside the paragraph.

Comment: Make some advances, but lost CSS, will continue working on it.